# How can I get the substring of every two characters from text in a textbox with an unknown length

Tags: c#

I'm working on a side project that generates code with four bytes of hex code (ex. 12 12 12 12) and I got the part down that generates it but I want to be able to use it this with any length of hex code (ex. 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12, basically any length) I don't know how though, here's what I have right now

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework;
using MetroFramework.Forms;

namespace CodeGenerator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void copyoutputBytesbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(outputbytesTxtbox.Text);
        }

        private void copyfullCodebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(fullcodeTxtbox.Text);
        }

        private void inputBytestxtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inputBytestxtbox.Text.Contains(" "))
            {
                string inputBytes = inputBytestxtbox.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                string f1 = inputBytes.Substring(0, 2);
                string f2 = inputBytes.Substring(2, 2);
                string f3 = inputBytes.Substring(4, 2);
                string f4 = inputBytes.Substring(6, 2);
                outputbytesTxtbox.Text = "0x" + f1 + " 0x" + f2 + " 0x" + f3 + " 0x" + f4;
                //original format: 12 12 12 12//
                //output format: 0x12 0x12 0x12 0x12//
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use any length of hex code not just four, is there anyway I can go about doing this?

Comment: An array? When you say "use" what are you actually trying to do, you don't do anything with the substrings here

Comment: in my actual code I do hold on ill add it to the question code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this code bellow, and give us feedback if it works fine:

```
private void inputBytestxtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (inputBytestxtbox.Text.Contains(" "))
            {
                const int step = 2;
                string inputBytes = inputBytestxtbox.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < inputBytes.Length; i+=step)
                {
                   string fx = inputBytes.Substring(i, step);
                   sb.Append("0x");
                   sb.Append(fx);
                   if(i <= inputBytes.Length - step)
                   {
                      sb.Append(" ");
                   }
                }
                outputbytesTxtbox.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "121212121212121"; // Your input form textblock
    string[] result = SplitByTwo(input); // splitting the string
    foreach (string s in result) // showing results
        Console.Write($"{s} ");
}

public static string[] SplitByTwo(string input)
{
    // the + 1 is here in case that the length is not divisible by 2
    // examle: if length is 6 the array kength must be 3 | (6 + 1) / 2 = 3 (integer division)
    //         if length is 7 the array length must be 4 | (7 + 1) / 2 = 4
    string[] output = new string[(input.Length + 1) / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < (input.Length + 1) / 2; i++)
    {
        if ((i * 2) + 1 == input.Length) // in case that the last split only contains 1 character
            output[i] = input.Substring(i * 2, 1);
        else
            output[i] = input.Substring(i * 2, 2);
    }
    return output;
}
```

output:

```
12 12 12 12 12 12 12 1
```

**EDIT:**

If your input has the spaces you can simply split the string and than join it back:

```
string input = "12 12 12 12 12 12 12 1";
string output = "0x" + string.Join(" 0x", input.Split(' '));
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
0x12 0x12 0x12 0x12 0x12 0x12 0x12 0x1
```

Comment: `input.Split(char c)` splits given string (input) into array of strings, the one given parameter is character by which it will split the given string. `string.Join(string s, string[] arr)` joins given array (in this case it was the output of `Split`) into single string with given string (`" 0x"`). And because the ` 0x` is written only between the string in the array you need to add another `0x` in forn to it. Hope that helps you understanding the code :).

Comment: nice this works too thanks for the explanation I appreciate it

Comment: anyway I could accept this as an answer too?